# being $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ two vectors with same length, how do I expand $(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b})^2$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, products

Let's say that I have two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$.
Assuming that they have same length, their product $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b}$
and its square $(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b})^2$ are scalars.

But what if I want to expand it? For example, before taking the derivative with regards to $\mathbf{a}$. What useful expression can $(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b})^2$ be transformed into?

My attempt was writing $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b}\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b}$ but then I am stuck.

Comment: I'd suggest just going to index notation i.e. $$(a^T b)^2=(\sum_i a_i b_i)^2=\sum_{ij}a_i b_i a_j b_j.$$ Either of the two latter expressions should be amenable to differentiation.

Comment: thank you for the comment, this could solve the issue. I was wondering if there is a more compact form to prevent digging  into the index notation.

Comment: I prefer to write it as $a^Tbb^Ta$, because expressions of the form $a^TMa$ where $M$ is a symmetric matrix are very common. The derivative is $2bb^Ta = 2(a^Tb)b$, which you can obtain from that form or via $\nabla(a^Tb)^2=2(a^Tb)\nabla(a^Tb)=2(a^Tb)b$.

Comment: @Rahul: thank you very much for your answer. May I ask you how did you transform $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b}\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b}$ into $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{a}$ ?

Comment: @Rahul, found out: I did not realize that, since $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b}$ is also a $1\times 1$ matrix and symmetric, then it holds that $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b} = (\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b})^T = \mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{a}$

Comment: Your scalar quantity is the traditional dot product. Second, the transpose of a one by one matrix (a scalar) is itself.